# Append words from variable to words from another variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to achieve something like the following code, where if a user entered for example (`you are bad`), it shows an alert. The below code isn't working because it alerts for the words (`you are`) only without reading what's in badAppend.

```
var badAppend= ["freak", "ugly", "bad"]
var badWords = [("you are"+badAppend)];
if((badWords)
    {
       alert("you cannot use this word/sentence");
       return false;
    }
```

I'm trying to ahcieve this to avoid doing like the following:

```
var badWords = ["you are bad", 'you are ugly", "you are freak"];
```

etc..

I'd really appreciate it much if anyone can help with this. regards.

Comment: Are you trying to create those sentences from the array, or check if they contain words, or ....... what ?

Comment: I'm trying to put restriction on all bad words appended to "you are". I'm not sure if you could get my point. @adeneo

Comment: What happens (or doesn't) with the code you have?

Comment: I hope you are trying to remove bad words from user input, how about writing a regex and cross checking it on every user input?

Comment: @JerryB, do you need badWords array? E.g. http://jsfiddle.net/w6q2gt2k/1/ If input string always starts with 'you are' it could make a sense, otherwise, you just have to check if input string contains one of bad words from badAppend (you can do it in loop)

Comment: The code I have works if the `badAppend` contains one word, like this `var badAppend= ["freak"]`  , so by using this `var badWords = [("you are"+badAppend)];` . It alerts when the user insert `you are freak` . However, if the `badAppend` contains multiple words like described in the question, it won't show any alert. @jonmrich

Comment: Don't know what you mean by `if ((badwords)`

Comment: Without a solid set of examples it's hard to tell what you expect to pass or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A more vanilla JavaScript way, on this one you do a "blacklist" check first against an array of "Bad Words" printing only the sentences that are allowed:

```
var words = document.getElementById('userInput').value.split(" ");
var badWords = ['array', 'of', 'bad', 'words'];
for (i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
    for (ii = 0; ii < badWords.length; ii++) {
        var exists = words.indexOf(badWords[ii]);
        if (exists != -1) {
            words.splice(exists, 1);
        }
    }
    var result = document.getElementById('notInside');
    result.innerHTML += words[i];
    result.innerHTML += "</br>";
}
```

I know he's using jQuery but just as another example to do this for other people that might need it. If you need to only display words that ARE in the array just do:

```
var words = document.getElementById('userInput').value.split(" ");
var badWords = ['array', 'of', 'bad', 'words'];
for (ii = 0; ii < badWords.length; ii++) {
    var exists = words.indexOf(badWords[ii]);
    if (exists > -1) {
        var result = document.getElementById('inside');
        result.innerHTML += words[exists];
        result.innerHTML += "</br>";
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually I found your code alerts anything inputted even if they are not on the `badWords` list. Can you edit that please? Thank you again. @Samuel Lopez

Comment: Hi @JerryB I thought you wanted to filter out words from user input, the second example is the one I think you're looking for, here's a jsFiddle demo: https://jsfiddle.net/noh5xq0a/12/

Comment: Great! thank you for the update, last question, can I put second array like this `var badAppend= ['this', 'is', 'bad', 'append'];` and if the user inputs: `words append` which is actually one word from the first array and one word from the second array, then if that combination exists, it outputs the alert? @Samuel Lopez

Comment: You would just add the new elements that you need to the first array like so: `badAppend.push("new"); badAppend.push("word");` this way you could even add word dynamically to you list depending on other events on your application e.g. if a user is under age you could append more words or if a user is an adult you could delete words from you list by finding the index of the element and splicing it like so: `object.splice(object.indexOf(element))` . BTW if you are using jQuery the examples below would be a better fit I believe, check them out too!

Answer (score 1):

```
var newWords = $(badAppend).map(function(item) { return "you are " + item; });
```

This will give you

```
newWords = [ "you are freak", "you are ugly", "you are bad" ];
```

Answer (score 1):

I would do something like this,

```
var match = $('div.text').text().match(/[yY]ou(('re)|(\sare))\s\w+/g);

if(match){
    match = match.map(function(item){
        return (item.substring(item.lastIndexOf(" ")+1)).toLowerCase();
    });

    var match2 = $(match).filter(badWordsArray);

    if(match2.length > 0){
        console.log('Bad word!');
    }else{
        console.log('Input is clean!');
    }

}else{
    console.log('Input is clean!');
}
```

Change the text selector in the first line to whatever you need.

This will go through all the text that user entered, matches all the words which were followed by one of these:

- You are
- You're
- you are
- You are

The `match` variable will be an array containing all those words, then you can filter it based on your bad word array to see if there was any bad word.

If there is non of those four "you are"s in the code it just logs the input is clean, otherwise it checks for bad words in lowercase.

If you are sure that you just need to match `'you are'` exactly, you can replace the regex with this one, it will run faster too. `/(you\sare)\s\w+/g`

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand, you have a dictionary of bad words and you are trying to prevent user from using those words. In that case, you can do the following:

```
var containsBadWords = function(words){
    var badWords = ['bad', 'ugly', 'freak' /* ...*/];
    var badWordCount = 0;
    words.forEach(function(word){
        if(badWords.indexOf(word)>-1) badWordCount++;
    });
    return badWordCount;
}

var userWords = 'i am bad you are bad';    
var result = containsBadWords(userWords.split(' '));    
if(result>0) alert();
```